# React.js and horizontal IScroll 5 with dynamic width

Tags: javascript, css, iscroll, reactjs

I cannot make IScroll to work with React.js.

```
var SubHeaderMenu = React.createClass({
getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {items: []};
},

componentDidMount: function () {
    if (this.props.items.length && this.isMounted()) {
        this.scroll = new IScroll(this.getDOMNode(), {
            scrollX: true,
            scrollY: false,
            mouseWheel: true,
        });
    }
},

render: function () {
    var itemNodes = this.props.items.map(function (item) {
        return <div key={item.name} className="subheader-item">{item.name}</div>;
    }.bind(this));

    return (
        <div className="bar bar-standard bar-header-secondary subheader">
            <div className="scroller" ref="scroller">
                <div className="scroller-inner" ref="scrollerInner">{itemNodes}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
});
```

SubHeaderMenu component receive list of items as props. This works fine if I set up width for `.scroller` in CSS:

```
.scroller { width: 600px; ... }
```

But without width in CSS it doesn't scroll..

How to handle dynamic width of every list item?

Answer (score 1):

There is a npm-package for react and IScroll:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-iscroll